# Facebook Apps not working

Tags: facebook, apache

My facebook applications started to fail for apparently no reason. I keep getting this error when trying to load the application: Error 324 net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I have valid ssl certificate, the application code is pretty basic and right (i've even tested an empty application and still doesnt work). Everything seems to be ok, but the truth is that it fails to work now.

One important thing is that when i access the application outside the facebook it works and maybe something is cached making it work next time i try to access it by facebook. If i clear the cache it fails to work again.

Checking the server logs i see no attempt of connection by facebook. Don't know if it's something related to apache server.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

It was a problem with apache. We just recompiled it (cpanel easy apache) and it works now.